# What is the best platform / technology / server for high quality video streaming?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming

I need to implement a video streaming broadcast for conferences but I have not experienced with this technology. I know there are open source projects, I am not so crazy to create it from scratch, but I would like to guide me to choose the best solution.

Does anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

On the Microsoft side, [IIS Smooth Streaming](http://www.iis.net/download/SmoothStreaming) is your best bet.

For free (as in beer) open source, [ffserver from FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffserver.html)  is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

vlc ( http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ ) worked excellent for me. i could stream h.264, mpeg, divx, change the format on demand, has a variety of ways to control it (http, rc, telnet, etc). it is extremely flexible

Answer (score 0):

www.ustream.tv
 use this. It rocks...

Comment: What does ustream.tv use exactly?

Comment: broadcast live from your camera,
using your computer,.. Its very easy to get started

Answer (score 0):

I do refer Hioxindia's [Live streaming](http://hioxindia.com/live-stream-hosting.php). Best quality that provides uninterrupted videos live to the users with no buffer time. Give it a try.